# xDocReport - Impossible to create report for the input stream

Tags: java, report, inputstream, seam3, xdocreport

I cannot manage with this problem. The source is:

```
        try {
        // 1) Load Docx file by filling Velocity template engine and cache it to the registry
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("/test.docx");
        IXDocReport report = XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport(in,TemplateEngineKind.Velocity);

        // 2) Create context Java model
        IContext context = report.createContext();
        context.put("user", variables.get("user"));

        // 3) Generate report by merging Java model with the Docx
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("/test_Out.docx"));
        report.process(context, out);

      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (XDocReportException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

When I'm trying to proceed this code I've got error:

```
09:03:15,608 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core.XDocReportException: Impossible to create report for the input stream. The report loader supports only [] files type.

09:03:15,608 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.registry.XDocReportRegistry.createReport(XDocReportRegistry.java:328)

09:03:15,608 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.registry.XDocReportRegistry.createReport(XDocReportRegistry.java:313)

09:03:15,608 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.registry.XDocReportRegistry.loadReport(XDocReportRegistry.java:285)

09:03:15,608 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.registry.XDocReportRegistry.loadReport(XDocReportRegistry.java:278)

09:03:15,608 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.registry.XDocReportRegistry.loadReport(XDocReportRegistry.java:264)
```

And it points to the line:

```
IXDocReport report = XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport(in,TemplateEngineKind.Velocity);
```

What does it mean - The report loader supports only [] files type.?
It there anything wrong with loading data from the InputStream?
I've no idea how to solve this. Please help!

Comment: Ok, got it. There was library for required type missing: fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.docx - so, there were no any types known :-)

Answer (score 6):

Your error means that you have not XDocReport **fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.docx** docx implementation JAR in your classpath. I suggest you to read the [Docx Reporting](http://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/wiki/DocxReportingJavaMain) which explains that and [XDocReport download samples](http://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/downloads/list) which contains the well JARs according that you wish to do (use Velocity/Freemarker, generatefrom  ODT, Docx...)